# Selenium chrome driver unable to locate input element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Getting error when trying to locate the input element. Tried locating by xpath and className.

HTML of the Input Element:

```
<input data-v-9182d0dc="" type="text" id="filterElement" data-cy="v-search-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type a name or a number" class="padding-right-30 round">
```

Xpath for this element:

```
//*[@id="filterElement"]
```

Full Xpath for this element: `/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/input`

Statement to find the element

```
temp=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/input')
```

Getting below error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/input"}
```

[image]

Update: The element seems to be inside an iframe. Not sure how this comes into play when selecting an element

Answer (score 0):

To locate the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#filterElement[data-cy='v-search-input']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='filterElement' and @data-cy='v-search-input']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: I am not even trying to click on the input element. Just trying to locate it. I have a time 3 sec sleep before i try to locate the input element.

Comment: @Chetan Neither I've invoked `click()` though the line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch the iframe. The input element was located inside another iframe.

Comment: I'm sure the first link from _**Reference**_ section of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71085122/7429447) must have helped you.